# How do I remove HTML tags from a list of strings that contain the same HTML tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have found a dozen ways to remove html and clean data scraped online in string format. My problem is the data I have scraped is in list format.

The code below will print out a list of data containing html tags.

```
price = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})
```

I have tried using .get_text at the end to remove html tags but I get an attribute error for the data being a list not a string

```
price = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "s-item__price"}).get_text()
```

This is the full script below..

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from html.parser import HTMLParser

URL = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=oneplus%206t&_sacat=0&rt=nc&_udlo=150&_udhi=450"
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

price = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "s-item__price"}).get_text()

print(price)

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

I want to accomplish this without the API**

Comment: Please use an online IDE or a pastebin link instead of pasting all of your code in the comments as these platforms format much better.

Comment: Put it in a for loop and run through all of the strings in `price`. You have to do this since `findAll` returns a list, not a string.

Comment: Can anybody help show me an example for loop i could add to that script, I have tried like 10 that i had in mind and none work. Can list but his post will get ridiculously long

Comment: I knew there was a stupid simple way to do that. Thanks so much man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `for`-loop and call `.get_text()` from it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=oneplus%206t&_sacat=0&rt=nc&_udlo=150&_udhi=450"
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for price in soup.findAll("span", {"class": "s-item__price"}):
    print(price.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
$449.99
$449.99
$414.46
$399.00
$399.95
$349.99
$449.00
$585.00
...and son on.
```

---

EDIT: To print title and price, you could do for example:

```
for tag in soup.select('li.s-item:has(.s-item__title):has(.s-item__price)'):
    print('{: <10} {}'.format(tag.select_one('.s-item__price').get_text(strip=True),
                              tag.select_one('.s-item__title').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')))
```

Prints:

```
$449.99    SPONSORED OnePlus 6T 128GB 8GB RAM A6010 - Midnight Black (Unlocked) Global Version
$449.99    OnePlus 6T 128GB 8GB RAM A6010 - Midnight Black (Unlocked) Global Version
$414.46    Oneplus 6t dual sim 256gb midnight black black 6.41" unlocked ram 8gb a6010
$399.00    SPONSORED OnePlus 6T A6013, Clean ESN, Unknown Carrier, Coffee
$399.95    SPONSORED OnePlus 6T 4G LTE 6.41" 128GB ROM 8GB RAM A6013 (T-Mobile)  - Mirror Black
$349.99    ONEPLUS 6T - BLACK - 128GB - (T-MOBILE) ~3841
$449.00    OnePlus 6t McLaren Edition Unlocked 256GB 10GB RAM Original Accessories Included
$434.83    OnePlus 6T 8 GB RAM 128 GB UK SIM-Free Smartphone (ML3658)
$265.74    Oneplus 6t
$241.58    New Listing OnePlus 6T 8GB 128GB UNLOCKED
$419.95    NEW IN BOX Oneplus 6T  128GB  Mirror Black (T-mobile/Metro PCS/Mint) 8gb RAM
$435.99    OnePlus 6T - 128GB 6GB RAM - Mirror Black (Unlocked) Global Version

... and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use get_text() on the list itself, but you can on the individual elements.

```
price_elems = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})
prices = [elem.get_text() for elem in price_elems]
```

Then you have a list of the actual text between the tags that you can print!
Hope that helps! :)